# Printing variable from within Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following code in my makefile:

```
S_RES=$(shell cat output)

echo -e "Serial result = \t" $(S_RES)
```

Basically, I want to store the output of the shell command `cat output` in the S_RES variable, and then echo that variable to the screen (with some explanatory text in front of it). I also want to be able to use the variable later on in my program. I thought I had followed the instructions given in various StackOverflow questions, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 44):

If simple space instead of escape sequence `\t` is allowed, and your `make` is
`GNU make` 3.81 or higher, `$(info)` is available.
For example:

```
$(info Serial result = $(S_RES))
```

If your `make`'s version is 3.80 or lower, `$(warning)` might meet the
purpose. However, `warning` prints line number etc. too.

**EDIT:**
For your information, the following makefile outputs `abc` on my GNU make 3.81.

```
A := $(shell echo abc)
$(info $(A))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I get 'Serial result = ' printed out, but not the value of S_RES. I assume I'm setting S_RES properly in the first place - is that correct?

Comment: Is your `make` `GNU-make`? If so, what is the version?
Please see the edit.

Comment: I get the following output:


    A := abc
    make: A: Command not found
    make: *** [test] Error 127

And my version of make is GNU Make 3.81

Comment: (Sorry for bad formatting, StackOverflow doesn't appear to let me edit comments more than 5 mins after they've been submitted.) Basically it appears that it tries to execute the line `A := abc` rather than using it as an instruction to store something in the variable `A`. The same error occurs even if I remove the `$(info $(A))` line

Comment: Hmm... Then, how about simple one line makefile `$(info $(MAKE))`?
If your `make` works properly, it will print your `make` command's name.

Comment: @robintw: Are you by any chance trying to do this within a rule?

Comment: @Beta - Yes I am. Should that make a difference?

Comment: @robintw: Definitely. What Ise Wisteria wrote is in "Make language", but Make passes the *commands* within the rule to subshells, which use a very different grammar. If you're trying to set a variable there and use it "later in [the] program", I suspect you misunderstand how makefiles work and what "later" means in that context. Perhaps you could edit your post to show the code *in situ* and tell us what the "program" is.

Comment: me too unable to print a variable residing in a make file. I'm trying to compile an Android NDK app and look at the variable inside `ndk-bundle/build/core/build-binary.mk`

Comment: OK, I'm able to print them. I couldn't before because I'm trying to print `$(PRIVATE_CXX)` before `define cmd-build-shared-library`.

Answer (score 7):

just a side note

this evaluates on use time, this is as many times as $(A) is used

```
A = something
```

this evaluates on parse time, thus the value is evaluates once

```
A := something
```